# How to classify information, according to three attributes, with dictionaries and collections?

Tags: vba, dictionary, collections

I'm trying to classify information according to their attributes.

I would like to classify the info by BROKER; then by OBS(ervation) and then the STOCK.

Raw Data to Classify
[image]

Output wanted
[image]

I tried with a Dictionary of collections nested with another collection. What I would like to do is:

1- Populate the dictionary with Brokers. If the brokerDict(broker) doesn't exist, add it.

2- Add to this brokerDict(broker) a collection with the OBS (executed, pending, etc.) for that broker.

3- Add to the previous collection, a collection2 of the Stocks corresponding to the OBS corresponding to the broker.

```vb
Public Sub MainBeta()
Dim brokerDict As New Dictionary
Dim obs As Variant
Dim stock As Variant
Dim broker As Variant
Dim C As Collection, D As Collection

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

Funct brokerDict

For Each broker In brokerDict
        
    Debug.Print broker; ":"
        
    For Each obs In D
            
        Debug.Print vbTab; obs
                
        For Each stock In C
                    
            Debug.Print vbTab; vbTab; stock
                        
        Next
    Next
Next

End Sub

Public Sub Funct(brokerDict As Dictionary)

Dim y As Range
Dim ObsRange As Range
Dim oRows

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
oRows = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown)))

With tblObs
    Set ObsRange = Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(oRows + 1, 2)) 'dynamic range
End With

For Each y In ObsRange
    obs = y
    broker = y.Offset(ColumnOffset:=-1)
    stock = y.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1)
    
    If Not brokerDict.Exists(broker) Then   'First time I see a broker
        Set C = New Collection
        Set D = New Collection
        C.Add Item:=stock                    'I add the broker, the obs associated and the stock associated to the obs
        D.Add Item:=C, key:=obs
        brokerDict.Add broker, D
    Else
        If Not brokerDict(broker).Exists(obs) Then   'the broker is already in Dict
            Set C = New Collection                  'But the obs is new
            Set D = New Collection               ' Adding obs and stock to broker
            C.Add Item:=stock
            D.Add Item:=C, key:=obs
            brokerDict(broker).Add D
        Else
            brokerDict(broker)(obs)(C).Add stock 'adding a stock to a obs and broker already present in dict and collection
        End If
            
    End If
Next y
      
End Sub
```

Comment: You can achieve exactly your desired output with a pivot table.

Comment: @PeterT not exactly because pivot table sumarize too much and doesn't show duplicates I have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My example below is not designed for efficiency, rather more for clarity. I've assumed that your "output" is more of an illustration how you want the data to be organized after you've built up the dictionaries. So this example will print the results to the Immediate window to show that your data are in the right places.

Do notice a couple of things...

1. Using `Const` definitions makes for a little more typing, but it really clears up any confusion in your code when you are referencing an index or something with a "magic number". Defining and using what the number actually means is a great help in understanding your own code.
2. The top-level routine only has three statements in it. This clearly outlines the major logic steps your program is taking and helps to organize in the programmer's mind what each step contributes to the solution. This is easier than reading through larger logic blocks and piecing the overall logic flow mentally.

Here is the example code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub BuildMyData()
    Dim data As Variant
    data = GetMyDataFrom("Sheet1")

    Dim transactions As Dictionary
    Set transactions = GetTransactionsFrom(data)
    
    '--- now do something here with your data dictionaries
    PrintToImmediateWindow transactions
End Sub

Private Function GetMyDataFrom(ByVal sheetName As String) As Variant
    '--- pull all the data into a memory-based array
    Dim dataRange As Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName)
        Dim lastRow As Long   'in your example data, this is 11
        Dim lastCol As Long   'in your example data, this will always be 3
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        lastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        '--- remember that this range is capturing the header row as well
        Set dataRange = .Range("A1").Resize(lastRow, lastCol)
    End With
    GetMyDataFrom = dataRange.Value
End Function

Private Function GetTransactionsFrom(ByRef data As Variant) As Dictionary
    Const BROKER_COL As Long = 1
    Const OBS_COL As Long = 2
    Const STOCK_COL As Long = 3
    
    Dim brokers As Dictionary
    Dim obs As Dictionary
    Dim stocks As Collection
    Set brokers = New Dictionary
    
    '--- loop through the first column of data to get all the brokers
    '    skipping the header row
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To UBound(data, BROKER_COL)
        If Not brokers.Exists(data(i, BROKER_COL)) Then
            '--- create a new observation and stock for this new broker
            Set obs = New Dictionary
            Set stocks = New Collection
            stocks.Add data(i, STOCK_COL)
            obs.Add data(i, OBS_COL), stocks
            brokers.Add data(i, BROKER_COL), obs
        Else
            '--- this is either a new observation and a new stock, or its
            '    just a new stock
            Set obs = brokers.Item(data(i, BROKER_COL))
            If Not obs.Exists(data(i, OBS_COL)) Then
                Set stocks = New Collection
                obs.Add data(i, OBS_COL), stocks
            Else
                Set stocks = obs(data(i, OBS_COL))
            End If
            stocks.Add data(i, STOCK_COL)
        End If
    Next i
    Set GetTransactionsFrom = brokers
End Function

Private Sub PrintToImmediateWindow(ByRef transactions As Dictionary)
    Dim transaction As Variant
    For Each transaction In transactions.Keys
        Dim observation As Variant
        Dim observations As Dictionary
        Set observations = transactions(transaction)
        For Each observation In observations
            Dim stock As Variant
            Dim stocks As Collection
            Set stocks = observations(observation)
            For Each stock In stocks
                Debug.Print transaction & " : " & observation & " : " & stock
            Next stock
        Next observation
    Next transaction
End Sub
```

Comment: The code works like a cham. Thank you very much!
My issue was I couldn't use a dictionary of dictionary because I was getting the error "the key is already in use". But I saw my error in your code. Correct me if I'm wrong. You are adding observations in the brokers Dict as an array, aren't you? So, Broker dict contains the Key "Goldman" and the key's item is an array containing "executed, pending, etc".

Comment: I'm gonna just edit your PrintToImmediateWindow to print the info exactly as it was required and then add a PrintToCell for people interested in print these categories in cells.

Comment: `obs` is a `Dictionary` all by itself. When it's added to the `brokers` dictionary, it doesn't go in as an array, but as a `Dictionary` object. So the dictionary `Item` is an object in this case. It's all objects until you start using the dictionary keys and/or the items in the Collection.